# angular velocity around ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, mathematical-astronomy

If I have velocity at perihelion/apphelion, distance away from sun at perihelion/apphelion, and orbital period. How can I find the angular velocity function for earth and subsequently all the other planets in the solar system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kepler's second law specifies

$$\frac1{2}r^2\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{\pi ab}{P},$$

where $P$ is the period and $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the semi-major and sem-minor axes, respectively, for the elliptical orbit.  This means that the constant rate -- at which a line segment between the planet and the sun sweeps out area -- equals the area of the ellipse divided by the time required to complete one orbit.

In polar coordinates the velocity is

$$\mathbf{v} = \frac{dr}{dt}\mathbf{e}_r + r\frac{d \theta}{dt}\mathbf{e}_{\theta},$$

and the magnitude of angular velocity is

$$\mathbf{\omega}= \frac{|\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}|}{r^2}= \frac{d \theta}{dt}.$$

Whence, 
$$\omega(r) = \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{2\pi ab}{Pr^2}.$$

Using some analytic geometry you can relate $a$ and $b$ to the perihelion ($d_p$) and aphelion ($d_a$) distances. Let the distance between the foci be $2c$.  Note that the center of the sun is located at one focus. We have the following relationships:

$$b^2 = a^2 - c^2,\\a+c = d_a,\\a-c= d_p.$$

Solving for $a$ and $b$ we get

$$a = \frac{d_a + d_p}{2}, \,\,\,\,b = \sqrt{d_ad_p}.$$

Substituting into the expression for angular velocity, we get

$$\omega(r) = \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{\pi }{Pr^2}(d_a + d_p)\sqrt{d_ad_p}.$$

Comment: Thank you! can you please explain the last part once again. Didn't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: You're welcome. In the last part I showed the equations you could use to specify $a$ and $b$ given the perihelion and aphelion distances.  I stopped short of writing the explicit solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried to understand but I still don't. Can you please exaplain? Forever grateful

Comment: Sure.  I expanded the answer.  Kepler's Second Law relates the angular velocity to the period of the orbit and the area of the ellipse (in terms of a and b).  You said you were given the perihelion and aphelion distances. I found the relationship between those distances and the semi-major and semi-minor axis lengths. Then I found the formula for angular velocity in terms of your given data.

Comment: Oh wow that makes so much more sense. Great Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry to be such a hassle but I don't understand how b^2=a^2-c^2. it doesn't make a triangle in the diagram i've drawn so how can that relationship be found?

Comment: An ellipse is the locus of points where the the sum of the distances to two fixed points (foci) is a constant. Let the foci be $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$.  The point $(a,0)$ is on the ellipse at one end of the major axis and the point $(0,b)$ is on the ellipse at an end of the minor axis. So $\sqrt{b^2 + c^2} + \sqrt{b^2 + (-c)^2} = (a-c) + (a -(-c))$. This implies $2 \sqrt{b^2+c^2} = 2a$ and $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=a$ and $b^2+c^2 = a^2$.  Hence, $b^2 = a^2 -c^2.$

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm literally forever grateful.

Comment: to calculate the angular velocity, should I take the average value of radius for "r" or how should I approach that? thanks once again.

Comment: Please help. Last query I promise. Do i use the average value of the radius for the r value in the angular velocity? Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for.  The angular velocity is a function of r -- so you can evaluate it if you know r (distance to sun) at any point of interest.

Comment: I'm looking to equate the angular velocity with time for two planets so that I can find the time of eclipse between them. to do this i will put the faster planet exactly 2π ahead of the slower one and equate for t. would this be right?

Comment: I need to think about that one a bit.

Comment: @Ireallyneedhelpthanks: I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you should post a new question.